# Cannot use cd command to change directory in Drush (win7)

Tags: windows, drupal, drush

I just installed Drush 6.0 on a Win7 machine. With cd command I can move around inside of C:\ but can't change to P:.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue you did a day or two ago.  I realized that the drush command prompt uses most of the same commands that the Windows command line does so I did a quick search along those lines and was able to find the answer.

You need to either type the drive you want to change to (with no other commands and no slash) or you can navigate to the directory but include '/D'.  Here are some examples.

P:

cd /D P:\wamp\www

Here is the website if you want more info:  http://www.windows-commandline.com/windows-7-command-line-switch-drives/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

install git bash and use this for your work on windows machine
or even better install linux as a virtual machine, as a developer you will love it after a few days

here is the link: https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=label:Featured